# Book where legendary sword type freezes hands when held except the main female character?

Tags: story-identification, books

Trying to find a fantasy book where the main character is a female warrior who holds a legendary sword. This sword is actually one of a series of swords (or type of sword) that freezes the hand of non-chosen wielders. The female warrior can fight normally with the sword. However, an army wielding the sword series has to fight in waves and hand off the sword when the wielder's hand gets too cold.

I believe the female warrior was also in a party. Thanks.

Comment: Last time I saw this trope was in a modern fantasy, and I know it's been done other times, so this might be a bit broad. See what I can find

Answer (score 4):

This is [The Siege by Troy Denning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Siege_(Forgotten_Realms_novel)), book two in the Return of the Archwizards series.

The female warrior is Keya and the sword is a *darksword*. The scene with the warriors passing the sword to each other is:

> They were surrounded by the Company of the Cold Hand, a hundred hand-picked
>   Spellblades chosen to wield the sixteen darkswords borrowed from the Vaasans
>   who had fallen when the phaerimm escaped their ancient prison. Because the
>   weapons would freeze the hand of any wielder not of the owning family, the
>   idea was that the first warrior would use the weapon until his hand grew too
>   cold to hold it, then pass it to the next, and so forth.